# LLVM Can't find getelementptr instruction

Tags: llvm

I have this byte code fragment:

```
define void @setGlobal(i32 %a) #0 {
entry:
  %a.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %a, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32* %a.addr, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* @Global, align 4
  %1 = load i32* %a.addr, align 4
  store i32 %1, i32* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i32]* @GlobalVec, i32 0, i64 0), align 4
  store i32 2, i32* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i32]* @GlobalVec, i32 0, i64 2), align 4
  ret void
}
```

I am using this code to find the getelementptr from "store i32 %1, i32* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i32]* @GlobalVec, i32 0, i64 0), align 4":

```
for (Module::iterator F = p_Module.begin(), endF = p_Module.end(); F != endF; ++F) {

        for (Function::iterator BB = F->begin(), endBB = F->end(); BB != endBB; ++BB) {

            for (BasicBlock::iterator I = BB->begin(), endI = BB->end(); I
                    != endI; ++I) {
                if (StoreInst* SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(I)) {
                    if (Instruction *gep = dyn_cast<Instruction>(SI->getOperand(1)))
                    {
                        if (gep->getOpcode() == Instruction::GetElementPtr)
                        {
                            //do something
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }
}
```

This code can't find the getelementptr. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no `getelementptr` instructions in your bitcode snippet, which is why you can't find them.

The two cases that look like a `getelementptr` instructions are actually [constant expressions](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions) - the telltale sign is that they appear as part of another instruction (`store`), which is not something you can do with regular instructions.

So if you want to search for that expression, you need to look for [type `GetElementPtrConstantExpr`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrConstantExpr.html), not `GetElementPtrInst`.